# Migrate Classic Auth 2010 Content DB to Claims Auth in SharePoint 2013, MigrateUsersToClaims return false

Tags: claims-based-auth

I am doing a two hop upgrades from SP2007 to SP2013. For testing I first upgraded a small content db from 2007 to 2010. The 2010 web application is still using classic auth.

Next I attach the 2010 db to 2013. I run Test-SPContentDatabase it show the inconsistency between claim and classic auth but the UpgradeBlocking show FALSE so I go ahead to mount the DB and upgrade.

The site collection is show up in the SP2013 farm, I can then upgrade the site to 2013 look and feel. I can login , view the content and also assign AD user permission too.

I learn from here (https://samlman.wordpress.com/2015/03/01/converting-a-classic-auth-content-database-to-claims-auth-in-sharepoint-2013/) perhaps I should convert the DB to Claims Auth, but the MigrateUsersToClaims return False in the result.

So I don't understand, Is it using Claim in the migrated site collection?

Is the MigrateUsersToClaims necessary ?

Answer (score 0):

If you created the 2013 Web Application in Classic mode, you will need to run `Convert-SPWebApplication` to convert the Web Application to Claims. If the Web Application is already Claims and you attach a Classic-enabled Content Database, you would run `Convert-SPWebApplication -Identity http://webAppUrl -From Legacy -To Claims -RetainPermissions`. This cmdlet is valid on SharePoint 2013 only and can be run each time you attach a Classic-enabled Content Database.

I recommend converting to Claims on SharePoint 2013, rather than on 2010 for the ability to fallback to SharePoint 2010.

Comment: My Web Application in 2013 is already in Claims, but my 2010 web app is in class.

Comment: That's fine. Just run the `Convert-SPWebApplication`.

Comment: Run on 2010 or 2013?

Comment: I've updated my answer to be more clear.